# Using "tic" without "toc" in Octave

Tags: octave, octave-gui

Quick background, Octave GUI version 6.2.0 takes at least 20-30 seconds to initialize on one computer, but 1-2 seconds on another computer running the same version and same OS. I wanted to figure out where the holdup was, so I used the `tic` and `toc` timer functions in various places within the `octaverc` startup file. At some point, I noticed that merely having `tic` at the very end of the startup file completely fixed the slow initialize time.

So while my main issue is resolved (though I don't know why that worked), I wanted to see if using `tic` without ever using `toc` in an Octave session can cause any issues, e.g., does this leave some timer process running in the background? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is bizarre!

Comment: perhaps the mere action of creating an .octaverc file saves octave from scanning directories trying to find an external one?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I'm modifying an existing .octaverc file though, it was already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tic` stores the current clock time in an internal variable (see `tic_toc_timestamp` [here](https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave/blob/fb1aef22fe28117915ca831a2597cc6a457f344e/libinterp/corefcn/data.cc#L6732), the source code for `tic` starts right after that line), `toc` compares the current clock time to the stored variable (see its source code [here](https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave/blob/fb1aef22fe28117915ca831a2597cc6a457f344e/libinterp/corefcn/data.cc#L6807)).

So, no, there’s no timer running in the background after you call `tic`.

Comment: I also noticed that while this works when running Octave directly, I have code that opens the Octave GUI and runs a script, all using a batch file, and when I do this, the initialization is still very slow, even with the `tic` command. I followed this instruction: 

[https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?53867]

but this didn't help. Are there any other known work-arounds for a slow start-up time for the Octave GUI?

Comment: @smcmi I don't know what is causing the slowdown or how to fix it, sorry.